# Simple and double quotes in cURL in groovy

Tags: jenkins, curl, groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline where this command works and send me a notification through google chat :

```
script {
    sh 'curl -k "https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAABHT3HT0/messages?key=*****&token=******" -d "@chat_notification.json" -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"'
}
```

But if I enter the url in a variable, that does not work any more :

```
script {
    url = "https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAAfF9CGEQ/messages?key=******&token=******"
    sh 'curl -k ${url} -d "@chat_notification.json" -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"'
}
```

With the error :

```
curl -k -d @chat_notification.json -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8'
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

It's probably a quote issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a quote issue try to use `""` instead of `''` to use the value of `url` variable in `curl` command. You should also seperate `-X` and `POST` (you have `-XPOST` in your script)

```
script {
    url = "https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAAfF9CGEQ/messages?key=******&token=******"
    sh "curl -k ${url} -d @chat_notification.json -X POST -H Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"
}
```

Comment: I try `sh "curl -k ${url} -d @chat_notification.json -XPOST -H Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"` but it's not working : `script.sh: line 1: -d: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are using single quotes in Groovy, that means you cannot interpolate the string with variables using the `$` syntax.
See https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation .
Same thing applies to shell code, by the way, or `sh` in this case.
But since you are not using any shell variables in your code, simply swapping the quotes, i.e. quoting your Groovy string with `"`, and using `'` within the curl command would probably work.